# undefined reference to `pthread_key_create' (linker error)

Tags: c++, googletest

I have downloaded gtest 1.7.0 sources from here:

https://code.google.com/p/googletest/downloads/list

and build the gtest .a files (lib files) on ubuntu 13.10:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the resulting lib is called: `libgtest.a`. In my main.cpp file Have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << "Test \n";
    int argc = 2;
    char* cp01;
    char* cp02;
    char* argv[] = {cp01, cp02};
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

From a terminal I build with:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include -L/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs -lpthread -lgtest
```

which gives the following errors:

```
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Based on this:
[error during making GTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315016/error-during-making-gtest)

I have also tried `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` but gives same error:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include -L/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs -pthread -lgtest
```

EDIT: I have also  tried to specifying `-pthread` as the last argument:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include -L/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs -lgtest -pthread
```

same error
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option `-lgtest` is attempting to link the dynamic library `libgtest.so`. You
wish to link the static library `/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.a`.

Instead of:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include -L/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs -lgtest -pthread
```

use:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include /home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.a -pthread
```

Note that your commandline supplies no name for the resulting executable, which will default
to `a.out`. If you want it called, e.g. `mytest`, then do:

```
g++ -o mytest main.cpp -I/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/include /home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.a -pthread
```

Comment: Yes forcing to use the static .a lib as you describe makes it work. Found something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986734/scons-how-to-force-use-of-static-library-over-shared . I also had to rename the .a file to start with "lib" like: libgtest-1.7.0-linux64.a instead of gtest-1.7.0-linux64.a

Comment: Odd. My build of gtest-1.7.0 generates no such file as `gtest-1.7.0-linux64.a`; I get `libgtest.a` in the `lib/.libs`dir. Anyhow, glad the prob is solved.

Comment: I renamed the files since I need to build for a range of platforms/archs. But a bit strange that it has to start with "lib", but its seems to be explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231206/lib-prefix-on-libraries

Comment: If using the dynamic lib is not ok, to what purpose does it serve? Is there a way to make this work using libgtest.so?

Answer (score 32):

You need to specify `-pthread` after `-lgtest`. The linker takes libraries in order, and only takes as much as it needs to resolve references which are undefined at that point.

Comment: Under clang++-3.8, the order is not the problem, but under g++ (version 5.4), the order is matter.

Comment: this is the only correct answer for that question. unbelievable all those other "workarounds" get upvotes!

Comment: I didn't know this ... Thank you! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Nope, the problem is with Gtest's build.

If you build it using the standard **configure** approach, it isn't supplying the `-lpthread` correctly to create `libgtest.so`.  Hence, when you try building a final shared library that actually uses the pthread capability it fails.

Instead, use the Cmake approach:

```
cd gtest-1.7.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
make
```

And then manually install these into `/usr/lib/`

This version correctly links in libpthread into libgtest.

Comment: This did it for me!  :-)

Comment: And how to uninstall the version with the wrong configuration whatsoever? I did what you wrote but it still gives the same error, probably it's still due to the previous installation.

Comment: This solution works. In encountered the problem with Debian 10 packaged `libgtest-dev`. After removing it and building this way it went smooth.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` (for linking with pthread-library), while you using gtest in your executable.

**OR**

Move the `-lpthread` after `libgtest.a` (sequence matters).

Answer (score 0):

To answer we probably need more information, are you on a 64 bit machine and downloaded a 32 bit library?

Comment: I have added some more details to my original post. Build gtest from source on ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.