# Failure linking when using an extra library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, pthreads, log4cplus

When I build a simple C++ program with `glog` library (Google's logging library which is not used in the code), I get "undefined reference" errors. When I remove the `-lglog` from the build command, the link succeeds.

Notice that the library that I added to the link is not used in the code at all and despite that it caused the build to fail. In addition, the `glog` and `log4cpp` libraries are supposed to be independent.

Can you explain this unusual behavior?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04

Code:

```
//test.cpp

#include "log4cpp/Appender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/FileAppender.hh"

int main() {
     log4cpp::Appender *appender;
     appender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("default", "program.log");
     return 0;
}
```

Working build command:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -llog4cpp -lpthread
```

Failing build command:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -llog4cpp -lglog -lpthread

//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT:

This command also builds successfully:

```
g++ test.cpp -llog4cpp -lpthread -lglog
```

This command fails (change the order of libs):

```
$ g++ test.cpp -llog4cpp -lglog -lpthread
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
//usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This succeeds:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -pthread -llog4cpp
```

This fails:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -pthread -llog4cpp -lglog
```

EDIT 2:

I studied the duplicate suggestions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)   and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error) to find out maybe there's something useful to me there, but it turned out irrelevant because these cases doesn't address the situation where a library that is not used in the code is added to the link and make it fail.

EDIT 3:

The files from my environment (glog libs, log4cpp libs, used log4cpp headers and test.cpp): [log_test.zip](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=86516243824302945748).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @IInspectable there are many answers in this post, can you please point me to the one that answers the question? Notice that the library that I added to the link is not used in the code at all and despite that it caused the build to fail.

Comment: @SleuthEye, originally I used `-pthread`, now I modified the question to be with `-lpthread`. I verified that it still has the same behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`pthread\_key\_create' (linker error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error)

Comment: @SleuthEye, from these answers, I can't see why the linker takes objects from `glog` library. The `test.cpp` code doesn't use anything from `glog` so why does the linker tries to insert it to the executable?

Comment: I still haven't got an answer to the question... can someone please explain the linker's behavior?