# Multiple definition in boost::thread while using kodo-rlnc in Omnet++

Tags: c++11, boost

Good evening!

During the use of a project called **kodo**, developed by [steinwurf](https://github.com/steinwurf) for random linear network coding in my simulation implemented in [Omnet++ (5.1pre2)](https://www.omnetpp.org/), my linker told me about a multiple definition of several functions. The output of `make` is quoted below:

```
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//simulation
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once_atomic.cpp.1.o): In Funktion
`boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)':
once_atomic.cpp:(.text+0x0): Mehrfachdefinition von
boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once.cpp.1.o):once.cpp:(.text+0x0): first 
efined here 
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once_atomic.cpp.1.o): In Funktion
`boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)':
once_atomic.cpp:(.text+0x150): Mehrfachdefinition von 
boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once.cpp.1.o):once.cpp:(.text+0x150): first defined here
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once_atomic.cpp.1.o): In Funktion 
boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)':
once_atomic.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): Mehrfachdefinition von 
boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'
./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a(once.cpp.1.o):once.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/gtest/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.1.o): undefined 
reference to symbol 'pthread_key_delete@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO aus der Kommandozeile fehlt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:111: die Regel für Ziel „out/gcc-debug//simulation“ scheiterte
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//simulation] Fehler 1
```

As you can see, there are several other multiple definitions and one unrecognized library (libgtest.a).

The kodo-rlnc downloaded from [1](https://github.com/steinwurf) and compiled, following the instructions of the [Steinwurf-Documentation](http://docs.steinwurf.com/kodo/kodo-rlnc/including_kodo_rlnc.html), downloaded itself the dependencies, also listed in [3](http://docs.steinwurf.com/kodo/kodo-rlnc/including_kodo_rlnc.html).

Now for me it looks like there's a failure in the boost-library itself, producing this multiple definition error. But since I'm not an expert C++ programmer, I may oversee some details.
I will post my code below, but keep attention at the include-section and the `Quelle::send_rlnc()` function, which uses the kodo-rlnc. You will notice, that it isn't used by the initially called `Quelle::initialize()` function. The Problem with the linking occured before using it's functionality. (This is pretty standard).
So here's my written code with the included kodo:

```
#include<omnetpp.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
#include<random>
#include<functional>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#include "payload_packet_m.h"

#include<kodo_core/object/file_encoder.hpp>
#include <kodo_rlnc/full_vector_codes.hpp>

#include<kodocpp/kodocpp.hpp>
#include<kodoc/kodoc.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class Quelle : public cSimpleModule{
    private:
        //uint32_t max_symbols;
        //uint32_t max_symbol_size;

        int is_rlnc;

        std::vector<uint8_t> readFile(const char* filename);

        void send_rlnc();
        void send_lnc();
    protected:
        virtual int calculate_vector_checksum(std::vector<unsigned int> input);
        virtual void initialize() override;
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(Quelle);

std::vector<uint8_t> Quelle::readFile(const char* filename){
    std::ifstream file("testfile.txt", std::ios::binary);

    file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    std::streampos fileSize;

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
    vec.reserve(fileSize);

    vec.insert(vec.begin(),
                std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(file),
                std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>());

    return vec;
}

int Quelle::calculate_vector_checksum(std::vector<unsigned int> input){
    int checksum = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator It;
    for(It = input.begin(); It != input.end(); It++){
        checksum += *It;
    }

    return checksum;
}

void Quelle::send_rlnc(){
    uint32_t max_symbols     = 16; //par("max_symbols");
    uint32_t max_symbol_size = 1400; //par("max_symbol_size");
    fifi::api::field field = fifi::api::field::binary8;

    using rlnc_encoder  = kodo_rlnc::full_vector_encoder;
    using rlnc_decoder  = kodo_rlnc::full_vector_decoder;

    rlnc_encoder::factory encoder_factory(field, max_symbols, max_symbol_size);
    auto encoder = encoder_factory.build();

    rlnc_decoder::factory decoder_factory(field, max_symbols, max_symbol_size);
    auto decoder = decoder_factory.build();

    std::vector<uint8_t> payload(encoder->payload_size());
    std::vector<uint8_t> block_in(encoder->block_size());

    std::generate(block_in.begin(), block_in.end(), rand);

    encoder->set_const_symbols(storage::storage(block_in));

    std::vector<uint8_t> block_out(decoder->block_size());
    decoder->set_mutable_symbols(storage::storage(block_out));

    uint32_t encoded_count = 0;

    while(!decoder->is_complete()){
        uint32_t bytes_used = encoder->write_payload(payload.data());


        ++encoded_count;

        EV << "Bytes used: " << bytes_used << " Encoded count: " << encoded_count << "\n";

        payload_packet *Datenpaket= new payload_packet("Datenpaket");
        Datenpaket->setBytesArraySize(payload.size());
        Datenpaket->setData_inArraySize(block_in.size());

        uint8_t checksum = 0;

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < payload.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setBytes(i,payload.at(i));
            checksum += payload.at(i);
        }

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < block_in.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setData_in(i,block_in.at(i));
        }

        EV << "Packet " << encoded_count <<" payload checksum: " << (unsigned int) checksum;

        int n = gateSize("out");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            payload_packet *temp = Datenpaket->dup();
            send(temp,"out",i);
        }

        delete Datenpaket;

        decoder->read_payload(payload.data());
    }
}

void Quelle::send_lnc(){
    uint32_t max_symbols     = 16; //par("max_symbols");
    uint32_t max_symbol_size = 1400; //par("max_symbol_size");


    // std::vector<uint8_t> testvector = readFile("testfile.txt");
    // EV << "File vector size: " << testvector.size() << "\n";

    kodocpp::encoder_factory encoder_factory(
        kodocpp::codec::full_vector,
        kodocpp::field::binary8,
        max_symbols,
        max_symbol_size);

    kodocpp::encoder encoder = encoder_factory.build();

    kodocpp::decoder_factory decoder_factory(
        kodocpp::codec::full_vector,
        kodocpp::field::binary8,
        max_symbols,
        max_symbol_size);

    kodocpp::decoder decoder = decoder_factory.build();

    std::vector<uint8_t> data_out(decoder.block_size());
    decoder.set_mutable_symbols(data_out.data(), decoder.block_size());

    std::vector<uint8_t> payload(encoder.payload_size());
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_in(encoder.block_size());

    //std::vector<unsigned int> random_data(32);
    std::generate(data_in.begin(), data_in.end(), rand);
    // for(unsigned int l=0; l < data_in.size(); l++){
    //     data_in.push_back( (uint8_t) "a");
    // }

    encoder.set_const_symbols(data_in.data(),encoder.block_size());
    //EV <<"Vector checksum: " << calculate_vector_checksum(data_in) << "\n";

    uint32_t encoded_count = 0;

    while(!decoder.is_complete()){
        uint32_t bytes_used = encoder.write_payload(payload.data());

        ++encoded_count;

        EV << "Bytes used: " << bytes_used << "\n";

        payload_packet *Datenpaket= new payload_packet("Datenpaket");
        Datenpaket->setBytesArraySize(payload.size());
        Datenpaket->setData_inArraySize(data_in.size());

        uint8_t checksum = 0;

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < payload.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setBytes(i,payload.at(i));
            checksum += payload.at(i);
        }

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < data_in.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setData_in(i,data_in.at(i));
        }

        EV << "Packet " << encoded_count <<" payload checksum: " << (unsigned int) checksum;

        int n = gateSize("out");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            payload_packet *temp = Datenpaket->dup();
            send(temp,"out",i);
        }

        delete Datenpaket;

        decoder.read_payload(payload.data());
    }

    EV << "Ecoded " << encoded_count << " packets!" << "\n";
}

void Quelle::initialize(){
    //cMessage *msg = new cMessage("Testmessage");
    uint32_t max_symbols     = 16; //par("max_symbols");
    uint32_t max_symbol_size = 1400; //par("max_symbol_size");

    is_rlnc  = par("is_rlnc");
    EV << "RLNC: " << is_rlnc << "\n";


    // std::vector<uint8_t> testvector = readFile("testfile.txt");
    // EV << "File vector size: " << testvector.size() << "\n";

    kodocpp::encoder_factory encoder_factory(
        kodocpp::codec::full_vector,
        kodocpp::field::binary8,
        max_symbols,
        max_symbol_size);

    kodocpp::encoder encoder = encoder_factory.build();

    kodocpp::decoder_factory decoder_factory(
        kodocpp::codec::full_vector,
        kodocpp::field::binary8,
        max_symbols,
        max_symbol_size);

    kodocpp::decoder decoder = decoder_factory.build();

    std::vector<uint8_t> data_out(decoder.block_size());
    decoder.set_mutable_symbols(data_out.data(), decoder.block_size());

    std::vector<uint8_t> payload(encoder.payload_size());
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_in(encoder.block_size());

    //std::vector<unsigned int> random_data(32);
    std::generate(data_in.begin(), data_in.end(), rand);
    // for(unsigned int l=0; l < data_in.size(); l++){
    //     data_in.push_back( (uint8_t) "a");
    // }

    encoder.set_const_symbols(data_in.data(),encoder.block_size());
    //EV <<"Vector checksum: " << calculate_vector_checksum(data_in) << "\n";

    uint32_t encoded_count = 0;

    while(!decoder.is_complete()){
        uint32_t bytes_used = encoder.write_payload(payload.data());

        ++encoded_count;

        EV << "Bytes used: " << bytes_used << "\n";

        payload_packet *Datenpaket= new payload_packet("Datenpaket");
        Datenpaket->setBytesArraySize(payload.size());
        Datenpaket->setData_inArraySize(data_in.size());

        uint8_t checksum = 0;

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < payload.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setBytes(i,payload.at(i));
            checksum += payload.at(i);
        }

        for(unsigned int i=0; i < data_in.size();i++){
            Datenpaket->setData_in(i,data_in.at(i));
        }

        EV << "Packet " << encoded_count <<" payload checksum: " << (unsigned int) checksum;

        int n = gateSize("out");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            payload_packet *temp = Datenpaket->dup();
            send(temp,"out",i);
        }

        delete Datenpaket;

        decoder.read_payload(payload.data());
    }

    EV << "Ecoded " << encoded_count << " packets!" << "\n";

    // std::vector<unsigned int> converted_values;
    //
    // for(unsigned int i=0; i < data_in.size(); i++){
    //     unsigned int temp = 0;
    //
    //     EV << "data_in Stelle " << i << ": " << (unsigned int) data_in[i] <<"\n";
    //
    //     temp = (unsigned int) data_in[i];//(data_in[i] << 8) | data_in[1];
    //
    //     EV << "Temp Stelle " << i << ": " << temp << "\n";
    //     converted_values.push_back(temp);
    // }
    //
    // EV <<"Vector checksum: " << calculate_vector_checksum(converted_values) << "\n";
    //
    // payload_packet *testpacket = new payload_packet("Testpaket");
    // testpacket->setBytesArraySize(data_in.size());
    //
    // for(unsigned int i=0; i< data_in.size();i++){
    //     testpacket->setBytes(i,data_in[i]);
    // }
    //
    // testpacket->setDaten(converted_values);
    //
    // EV << "Generated a message";
    // int n = gateSize("out");
    // for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    //     payload_packet *temp = testpacket->dup();
    //     send(temp,"out",i);
    // }

    //delete testpacket;
}

void Quelle::handleMessage(cMessage *msg){
    //EV << "Received a message! Something is gone wrong!";
}
```

I'm sure that you recognized the creepy handling of the `std::vector<uint8_t> payload` while putting it into the `payload_paket *Datenpaket`. For some reason the Omnet++-packet-definition can't handle a pre-defined `std::vector<uin8t_t>`, so I had to declare an array for this and copy the content of my `payload` to the `bytes` array. But this doesn't matter for my question.

Does somebody have an idea what is wrong with my code or can give me a hint that it may be not my fault?

I appreciate any help with this!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT #1:**

I use a Makefile for the compiling process with linked static and shared libraries. The order structure can be described as: `sim_folder/libs/ many_libs_in_subdirectories` and `sim_folder/include/ many includes in subdirectories`.
My Makefile looks like this:

```
#
# OMNeT++/OMNEST Makefile for simulation
#
# This file was generated with the command:
#  opp_makemake -f -I./include -l libkodoc.so
#

# Name of target to be created (-o option)
TARGET = simulation$(EXE_SUFFIX)

# User interface (uncomment one) (-u option)
USERIF_LIBS = $(ALL_ENV_LIBS) # that is, $(TKENV_LIBS) $(QTENV_LIBS) $(CMDENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(CMDENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(TKENV_LIBS)
#USERIF_LIBS = $(QTENV_LIBS)

# C++ include paths (with -I)
INCLUDE_PATH = -I./include -I../Omnetpp/omnetpp-5.1pre2/include/omnetpp -I./include/kodo-rlnc #-I./include/platform -I./include/sak -I./include/kodo_core -I./include/fifi -I./include/storage -I./include/boost -I./include/endian -I./include/hex

# Additional object and library files to link with
EXTRA_OBJS =

# Additional libraries (-L, -l options)
#LIBS = libkodoc.so
LIBS =  libkodoc.so \
        ./libs/fifi/libfifi.a \
    ./libs/cpuid/src/cpuid/libcpuid.a \
    ./libs/gtest/libgtest.a \
    ./libs/sak/libsak.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_chrono.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_filesystem.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_iostreams.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_program_options.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_system.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_timer.a \
    ./libs/boost/libboost_thread.a \
    ./libs/gauge/src/gauge/libgauge.a \
    ./libs/tables/src/tables/libtables.a

#-L./libs/allocate -L./libs/cpuid -L./libs/fifi/ -L./libs/gtest -L./libs/kodo-core -L./libs/sak -L./libs/stub -L./libs/boost -L./libs/endian -L./libs/gauge -L./libs/hex -L./libs/platform -L./libs/storage -L./libs/tables

# Output directory
PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR = out
PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH =
O = $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)/$(CONFIGNAME)/$(PROJECTRELATIVE_PATH)

# Object files for local .cc, .msg and .sm files
OBJS = \
    $O/eve.o \
    $O/Quelle.o \
    $O/Router.o \
    $O/Senke.o \
    $O/txc1.o \
    $O/nc_packet_m.o \
    $O/payload_packet_m.o

# Message files
MSGFILES = \
    nc_packet.msg \
    payload_packet.msg

# SM files
SMFILES =

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pull in OMNeT++ configuration (Makefile.inc)

ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE)
else
ifneq ("$(OMNETPP_ROOT)","")
CONFIGFILE = $(OMNETPP_ROOT)/Makefile.inc
else
CONFIGFILE = $(shell opp_configfilepath)
endif
endif

ifeq ("$(wildcard $(CONFIGFILE))","")
$(error Config file '$(CONFIGFILE)' does not exist -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc)
endif

include $(CONFIGFILE)

# Simulation kernel and user interface libraries
OMNETPP_LIBS = $(OPPMAIN_LIB) $(USERIF_LIBS) $(KERNEL_LIBS) $(SYS_LIBS)

COPTS = $(CFLAGS) $(IMPORT_DEFINES)  $(INCLUDE_PATH) -I$(OMNETPP_INCL_DIR)
MSGCOPTS = $(INCLUDE_PATH)
SMCOPTS =

# we want to recompile everything if COPTS changes,
# so we store COPTS into $COPTS_FILE and have object
# files depend on it (except when "make depend" was called)
COPTS_FILE = $O/.last-copts
ifneq ("$(COPTS)","$(shell cat $(COPTS_FILE) 2>/dev/null || echo '')")
$(shell $(MKPATH) "$O" && echo "$(COPTS)" >$(COPTS_FILE))
endif

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# User-supplied makefile fragment(s)
# >>>
# <<<
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main target
all: $O/$(TARGET)
    $(Q)$(LN) $O/$(TARGET) .

$O/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)  $(wildcard $(EXTRA_OBJS)) Makefile $(CONFIGFILE)
    @$(MKPATH) $O
    @echo Creating executable: $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $O/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) $(LIBS) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean cleanall depend msgheaders smheaders

.SUFFIXES: .cc

$O/%.o: %.cc $(COPTS_FILE) | msgheaders smheaders
    @$(MKPATH) $(dir $@)
    $(qecho) "$<"
    $(Q)$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(COPTS) -o $@ $<

%_m.cc %_m.h: %.msg
    $(qecho) MSGC: $<
    $(Q)$(MSGC) -s _m.cc $(MSGCOPTS) $?

%_sm.cc %_sm.h: %.sm
    $(qecho) SMC: $<
    $(Q)$(SMC) -c++ -suffix cc $(SMCOPTS) $?

msgheaders: $(MSGFILES:.msg=_m.h)

smheaders: $(SMFILES:.sm=_sm.h)

clean:
    $(qecho) Cleaning...
    $(Q)-rm -rf $O
    $(Q)-rm -f simulation simulation.exe libsimulation.so libsimulation.a libsimulation.dll libsimulation.dylib
    $(Q)-rm -f ./*_m.cc ./*_m.h ./*_sm.cc ./*_sm.h

cleanall: clean
    $(Q)-rm -rf $(PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR)

# include all dependencies
-include $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)
```

As you can see there are several files included in my project (eve.cc, Router.cc, Quelle.cc ...). But the only class, that includes kodo-rlnc is the **Quelle.cc** I posted before.

Still thanks for any help!

**EDIT #2**

I managed to fix the multiple definition error by an quick&dirty approach: I forced the **once.cpp** to not include the **once_atomic.cpp**. This actually isn't a general fix but it may be sufficient for my purpose. But since I don't know which library may need the funtions of **once_atomic.cpp** too, the future proofness is unpredictable.

Now I'm still working at the **undefined reference**-issue.

**EDIT #3**

This morning I've figured out how to fix the issue with the undefined reference. First of all I needed to declare an additional option while linking the **libgtest.a**. Instead of `./libs/gtest/libgtest.a` the correct form was `./libs/gtest/libgtest.a -pthread`.
But that didn't fix the whole problem: As a newbie using the gcc, I forgot to check the linking order. Following the hint in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error) I managed to enable a cycle-group within the linked libs with `-Wl,--start-group -la -lb -lc -Wl,--end-group`.

So with the first issue dirty-fixed and the second issue normally fixed,my project began to work.

For me the topic is **closed** now.

But does anybody may tell me how to fix the first issue in a clear normal way?
It would be great to not depend on a dirty solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the edit sections, my problems were fixed by a quick&dirty solution. It appears to be working till now and hopefully likewise in the future.

To fix the multiple dfinition in `once.cpp` and `once_atomic.cpp` simply comment the include of the `once_atomic.cpp` in the `once.cpp` of boost::thread.

```
//#include "./once_atomic.cpp"
```

To fix the second issue with the undefined reference to a symbol within the gtest::pthread it just needed two simple entries in the Makefile:

Within the LIBS declare additionally: `./libs/gtest/libgtest.a -pthread` and add a cycle group to the compile statement around the LIBS:

```
$(Q)$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $O/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) -Wl,--start-group $(LIBS) -Wl,--eng-group $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS)
```

This did it for me. But maybe somebody can tell me a better and smoother solution for my problems!

Thanks in advance!